# Calculate unique time given multiple start and end dates

Tags: javascript, php, datetime, math, formula

If you have an array of appointments with start and end dates how do you calculate the unique time for all of the appointments?

Example:

```
var appointments = {
    0:{"start":"2015-01-20 09:00:00","end":"2015-01-20 09:30:00"},
    1:{"start":"2015-01-20 09:15:00","end":"2015-01-20 09:42:22"},
    2:{"start":"2015-01-20 10:00:00","end":"2015-01-20 10:25:00"},
    3:{"start":"2015-01-20 10:10:00","end":"2015-01-20 10:53:00"}
}
```

So in this example I would want to get a unique time (activity) value of 1H 35M 22S.
Anyone know any formulas for this?

So far I have this, seems to work but I think dates have to be sorted by start time. Is this the most efficient way to calculate this?:

```
var totalElapsedAppointmentSeconds = 0;
var lastActiveTimestamp;

for (i in appointments) {
    if (totalElapsedAppointmentSeconds == 0) {
        totalElapsedAppointmentSeconds = new Date(appointments[i].end) - new Date(appointments[i].start);
        lastActiveTimestamp = new Date(appointments[i].end);
    } else {
        if (new Date(appointments[i].start) < lastActiveTimestamp) {
            if (new Date(appointments[i].end) > lastActiveTimestamp) {
                totalElapsedAppointmentSeconds += new Date(appointments[i].end) - lastActiveTimestamp;
                lastActiveTimestamp = new Date(appointments[i].end);
            } else {
                //nothing, already completely accounted for
            }
        } else {
            totalElapsedAppointmentSeconds += new Date(appointments[i].end) - new Date(appointments[i].start);
            lastActiveTimestamp = new Date(appointments[i].end);
        }
    }
}

totalElapsedAppointmentSeconds = totalElapsedAppointmentSeconds/1000;
var totalElapsedTime = Math.floor(totalElapsedAppointmentSeconds / 3600) + "H " + Math.floor((totalElapsedAppointmentSeconds % 3600)/60) + "M " + (totalElapsedAppointmentSeconds % 3600) % 60 + "S";
console.log("totalElapsedTime",totalElapsedTime);
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: @Hassan The only thing I can think of is to have an array of minutes and reiterate over each date marking the minutes in the array, subsequent dates will just overwrite the same minutes when there is overlap so at the end I would have an array that would give me the total unique minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unclear what you are asking but this demonstrates calculating a time difference

**EDIT** whoops javascript says these are invalid dates, where did they come from?

[moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) is a good option to parse them if you must use these as inputs

```
var data = {
  "appointments": {
    0:{"start":"2015-01-20 09:00:00","end":"2015-01-20 09:30:00"},
    1:{"start":"20-01-2015 09:15:00","end":"20-01-2015 09:42:22"},
    2:{"start":"20-01-2015 10:00:00","end":"20-01-2015 10:25:00"},
    3:{"start":"20-01-2015 10:10:00","end":"20-01-2015 10:53:00"},
  }
}

function secondsDifference(ts1, ts2){
  startMs = new Date(ts1).valueOf();
  endMs = new Date(ts2).valueOf();
  deltaMs = endMs - startMs;
  deltaS = deltaMs /1000;
  deltaS = Math.floor(deltaS);
  return deltaS;
}

var a = data.appointments[0];
var result = secondsDifference(a.start, a.end);
console.log('first appointment length seconds:', result)
```

Comment: I guess I would say I am trying to calculate the total activity for 1 day but only unique time so all time when no appointments were happening is excluded.

Comment: There are many approaches, I would loop through the appointments, keeping track of `totalElapsedAppointmentSeconds` and `lastActiveTimestamp`. If there's an overlap, count from the earlier appointment end. If there's a gap, count from the later appointment start.

Comment: Thanks for that, I have created a working solution for that.